# Karate Driver connection refused error while using driver type 'Chrome' and executable batch file pointing to chrome.exe path

Tags: karate

Karate Driver Error: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to localhost:9515 ... failed: Connection refused: 
During karate script execution on Web testing , the error "poll attempt #1 to #20 for port to be ready - localhost:9515" is displayed.

Note: I am using karate-core-0.9.3.jar and trying to run the example 1 (demo-01.feature) from page :https://intuit.github.io/karate/karate-core/

Background:
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'chrome.bat'}

Note: Batch file (chrome.bat) is created and placed in the same location as that of feature file.

Batch file content as below.
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" %*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the same location as that of feature file.

That may not be what is expected. Either make sure that location is in the [System PATH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PATH_(variable)) or use the full absolute path in the `executable`. So also try this:

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome', executable: 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Google/Chrome/Application/chrome.exe' }
```

Actually since this is the default, even this should work for you !

```
* configure driver = { type: 'chrome' }
```

Read the docs: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop/karate-core#configure-driver

Finally if you are still stuck, please try the ZIP release: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/ZIP-Release

Comment: Thanks Peter.  * configure driver = { type: 'chrome' } worked for me.  Would like to know are there any RPA features are embedding to Karate framework....  for example  https://robotframework.org/rpa/ features are offered along with UI automation.

Comment: that's not a priority, but I'm confident it will happen with community contribution. also see this: https://github.com/ptrthomas/karate-sikulix-demo - karate has all the capabilities of the robot framework - so you can suggest a specific use-case you would like to see

Comment: Thanks for sharing. I will try this on desktop apps.